# Making the Field Horizontally Centered in Blackberry

Tags: layout, blackberry, field, center

These are 6 Dashboard Buttons: Which needs to be Horizontally Centered

[image: Dashboard Buttons]

```
  ![\[1\]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jg6q8.png][1]
```

The current Code is Like:

```
            DashboardButtons = new VerticalFieldManager(Field.USE_ALL_WIDTH
                            | VerticalFieldManager.FIELD_HCENTER));

                    ButtonRow1 = new HorizontalFieldManager(Field.USE_ALL_WIDTH
                            | HorizontalFieldManager.FIELD_HCENTER);
                    ButtonRow2 = new HorizontalFieldManager(Field.USE_ALL_WIDTH
                            | HorizontalFieldManager.FIELD_HCENTER);
```

And the Fields are defined like :
                  b1 = new Field(Field.FOCUSABLE|FIELD_HCENTER)

And inside the fields I have added the Button images.

The icon at the top (got centered) is added directly inside a VerticalFieldManager defined with Field.USE_ALL_WIDTH| VerticalFieldManager.FIELD_HCENTER` And the icon field with FIELD_HCENTER

Comment: Put HCENTER in HorizontalFieldManager Only.

Remove it from DashboardButtons...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am giving you a sample code according to that you can modify:

> If you want the focus on images, You should give one image in ONFOCUS and another image on UNFOCUS.

Below is the sample code:

```
public class LoadingScreen extends MainScreen
{   
Font font;
VerticalFieldManager vertical;
Bitmap bitmap=Bitmap.getBitmapResource("btn_send.png");
BitmapField bitmapField;
ButtonField plus,minus;
int px=0;
int py=0;
public LoadingScreen()
{
    font=Font.getDefault().derive(Font.BOLD, 18);           
    createGUI();
}

public void createGUI() 
{
    vertical=new VerticalFieldManager(USE_ALL_WIDTH);

    HorizontalFieldManager hor=new HorizontalFieldManager(Field.FIELD_HCENTER);

    BitmapField bitmapField=new BitmapField(bitmap);        
    hor.add(bitmapField);
    vertical.add(hor);

    HorizontalFieldManager hr=new HorizontalFieldManager(Field.FIELD_HCENTER);

    BitmapField bitmapField1=new BitmapField(bitmap);       
    hr.add(bitmapField1);

    BitmapField bitmapField2=new BitmapField(bitmap);
    hr.add(bitmapField2);

    BitmapField bitmapField3=new BitmapField(bitmap);
    hr.add(bitmapField3);
    hr.setPadding(10, 0, 10, 0);
    vertical.add(hr);

    HorizontalFieldManager hr1=new HorizontalFieldManager(Field.FIELD_HCENTER);

    BitmapField bitmapField4=new BitmapField(bitmap);       
    hr1.add(bitmapField4);

    BitmapField bitmapField5=new BitmapField(bitmap);
    hr1.add(bitmapField5);

    BitmapField bitmapField6=new BitmapField(bitmap);
    hr1.add(bitmapField6);
    hr1.setPadding(10, 0, 10, 0);

    vertical.setBackground(BackgroundFactory.createSolidBackground(Color.GREEN));       
    vertical.add(hr1);      
    add(vertical);
}       
}
```

I got like this below Image:

[image: Images in Center]

Comment: Thanks Ali Shaik..the setpadding() method is important here. When I declared that,then it got centered.

Comment: setpaddint() is not important Field.FIELD_HCENTER is Important

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8810304/making-the-richtextfield-horizontally-centered-in-blackberry