# Making the RichTextField Horizontally Centered in Blackberry

Tags: layout, blackberry, field, center, richtext

My current Mainscreen looks like :

[image]

The current code for each line of display is like:

```
    RichTextField WeFix1 = new RichTextField("• Computer & Laptop", RichTextField.TEXT_JUSTIFY_HCENTER);

    VFMTitle1 = new VerticalFieldManager(Field.USE_ALL_WIDTH| Field.NON_FOCUSABLE);

    HFMTitle1 = new HorizontalFieldManager(FIELD_HCENTER);

    HFMTitle1.add(WeFix1);

  VFMTitle1.add(HFMTitle1);
add(VFMTitle21);
```

But need to it be positioned in a straight line :

[image]

Comment: means do you want background for each line as gray color? or you need stright lines Right most and Left most position of the screen?

Comment: Try to use Label field instead RichTextField

Comment: Because RichTextField takes all the width and it doesn't give any field add beside to it. At this time you have to use sublayout() method to provide some width and height; and give some padding to place middle of the screen. That's why better to use LabelField

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many possibilities. You can adjust the margin of the container that holds list of services. Also you can make your custom field manager, and many more.

Option 1: Adjusting margin

```java
VerticalFieldManager vfmServices = new  VerticalFieldManager(VerticalFieldManager.USE_ALL_WIDTH);

vfmServices.add(new RichTextField("• Computer & Laptop"));
vfmServices.add(new RichTextField("• Modem / Router / Switches"));
vfmServices.add(new RichTextField("• Printer / Scanner"));
vfmServices.add(new RichTextField("• Tablet"));

final int horizontalMargin = 30;
vfmServices.setMargin(0, horizontalMargin, 0, horizontalMargin);

add(vfmServices);
```

Option 2: Using a custom field Manger

```java
VerticalFieldManager vfmServiceLists = new VerticalFieldManager(VerticalFieldManager.USE_ALL_WIDTH);

vfmServiceLists.add(new RichTextField("• Computer & Laptop"));
vfmServiceLists.add(new RichTextField("• Modem / Router / Switches"));
vfmServiceLists.add(new RichTextField("• Printer / Scanner"));
vfmServiceLists.add(new RichTextField("• Tablet"));

Manager mListContainer = new Manager(Manager.USE_ALL_WIDTH) {

    final int horizontalMargin = 30;

    protected void sublayout(int width, int height) {
        // this manager designed to contain only one list container.
        if (getFieldCount() == 1) {
            Field child = getField(0);
            layoutChild(child, width - 2 * horizontalMargin, height);
            // adjust manager height.
            height = child.getHeight();
            setPositionChild(child, horizontalMargin, 0);
        }

        setExtent(width, height);       
    }           
};

mListContainer.add(vfmServiceLists);
add(mListContainer);
```

[Added Later]

As [alishaik786](https://stackoverflow.com/users/822327/alishaik786) suggested in comment, if you use LabelField instead of RichTextField, you can check following code, which doesn't use any margin:

```java
VerticalFieldManager vfmServiceLists = new VerticalFieldManager();

vfmServiceLists.add(new LabelField("• Computer & Laptop"));
vfmServiceLists.add(new LabelField("• Modem / Router / Switches"));
vfmServiceLists.add(new LabelField("• Printer / Scanner"));
vfmServiceLists.add(new LabelField("• Tablet"));

Manager mListContainer = new Manager(Manager.USE_ALL_WIDTH) {
    protected void sublayout(int width, int height) {
        // this manager designed to contain only one list container.
        if (getFieldCount() == 1) {
            Field child = getField(0);
            layoutChild(child, width, height);
            // adjust manager height.
            height = child.getHeight();
            setPositionChild(child, (width - child.getWidth()) / 2, 0);
        }

        setExtent(width, height);       
    }           
};

mListContainer.add(vfmServiceLists);
add(mListContainer);
```

Comment: This code not suit for all devices because we have to change the horizontalMargin for every device. Try to use Label field instead RichTextField. Then you must get solution. If you want in RichTextField only use the Rupak code;

Comment: Yes, this code may not work on all devices, and I didn't write that  for solving generic issue. But adjusting the margin according to Display width, height is not that hard.

Comment: Rupak and @alishaik786 thanks for your solutions...  Rupak's Last code without any margin and RichTextField seemed to be a perfect solution!!!!

Answer (score 1):

> Better to use LabelField instead of RichTextField.
>   If you want the result on only RichTextField the below code is not suit for you; Then try to use our "Rupak" code;

This below code uses **LabelField** instead of **RichTextField**;

```
public class Abc extends MainScreen
{
VerticalFieldManager vertical;
Font font=Font.getDefault().derive(Font.BOLD, 18),small_font=Font.getDefault().derive(Font.PLAIN, 15);
LabelField labelField,labelFieldTwo;
public Abc() 
{
    createGUI();
}

private void createGUI() 
{
    vertical=new VerticalFieldManager(USE_ALL_WIDTH);
    vertical.setBackground(BackgroundFactory.createSolidBackground(Color.GREEN));
    HorizontalFieldManager hor=new HorizontalFieldManager(Field.FIELD_HCENTER);     

    hor.add(new LabelField(" We Fix ", Field.NON_FOCUSABLE));
    hor.setFont(font);
    hor.setPadding(5, 0, 5, 0);
    vertical.add(hor);

    HorizontalFieldManager hr=new HorizontalFieldManager(Field.FIELD_HCENTER);

    hr.add(new LabelField("."));        
    hr.add(new LabelField("Computer Science & Laptop", Field.NON_FOCUSABLE));
    hr.setFont(small_font);
    vertical.add(hr);

    HorizontalFieldManager hr1=new HorizontalFieldManager(Field.FIELD_HCENTER);

    hr1.add(new LabelField("."));       
    hr1.add(new LabelField("Modem/Router/Switches", Field.NON_FOCUSABLE));
    hr1.setFont(small_font);
    vertical.add(hr1);

    //------------------- Up to now you want like this; and you can do like this type also like left align and right align;
    HorizontalFieldManager hr2=new HorizontalFieldManager(Field.FIELD_LEFT);

    hr2.add(new LabelField("."));       
    hr2.add(new LabelField("Printer/Scanner", Field.NON_FOCUSABLE));
    hr2.setFont(small_font);
    vertical.add(hr2);

    HorizontalFieldManager hr3=new HorizontalFieldManager(Field.FIELD_LEFT);

    hr3.add(new LabelField("."));       
    hr3.add(new LabelField("Tablet", Field.NON_FOCUSABLE));
    hr3.setFont(small_font);
    vertical.add(hr3);

    HorizontalFieldManager hr4=new HorizontalFieldManager(Field.FIELD_RIGHT);

    hr4.add(new LabelField("."));       
    hr4.add(new LabelField("Printer/Scanner", Field.NON_FOCUSABLE));
    hr4.setFont(small_font);
    vertical.add(hr4);

    HorizontalFieldManager hr5=new HorizontalFieldManager(Field.FIELD_RIGHT);

    hr5.add(new LabelField("."));       
    hr5.add(new LabelField("Tablet", Field.NON_FOCUSABLE));
    hr5.setFont(small_font);
    vertical.add(hr5);

    vertical.setPadding(0, 0, 10, 0);
    add(vertical);
}
}
```

I got like this when field align **center, right and left**:

[image]

Comment: I think you are new to blackberry. To clarify your and our doubts come on the this chat room:  http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4014/knowledge-sharing-center-for-blackberry-and-java

Comment: LabelField did not help to make the Fields align in a straight line like in image two..

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
LabelField lbl=new LabelField("• Computer & Laptop\r\n• Modem / Router / Switches\r\n• 
Printer / Scanner\r\n• Tablet",LabelField.FIELD_HCENTER);
```